# Android shared prefrance

Tags: android

hi
 i have using shared preference for saving user name and password ,but when my application crashes i lost  my data,i need to re login again(Only some crashes i lost the data  ),how can i solve this problem ?

SharedData.userInfo = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
  SharedData.userAdd = SharedData.userInfo.edit();
  SharedData.userAdd.putString("userEmailAddress", uname);
  SharedData.userAdd.putString("userPassword", upassword);
  SharedData.userAdd.commit();

Comment: Maybe the crash happens before the app commit changes on the preferences editor. Could you post the code?

Comment: are you sure you're using Editor.commit() ? (Though I believe you are using it) Please post the code so that we can understand

Comment: Maybe your app shouln't crash...

Answer (score 2):

I use it like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit = sharedPref.edit();
prefEdit.putString("VariableName","Value");
prefEdit.commit();
```

and it works for me always.